# How to combine Android Studio based Application with Pastec Image Recognition (Which is C++ based)?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, image-recognition

I am wondering how to combine an **Android Studio** based **App** with **Pastec.io Open Source Image Recognition** Software. 
Currently the **cmake** file is compiled and made using **Ubuntu 16.04** as it requires (14.1 and above to do so).

I need to run the Pastec system from within the application in order to process the image but I don't have much experience with C++.

Any help would be much appreciated!! and any further information I can give I will.